# Approach to build a modularity Java (Web) Application

Tags: spring, osgi

I'm on the way to build a modular Java web project with some pluggable modules - like Jira and Confluence for example.
My first thought was to build a project with Spring and OSGi, I started finding a workable OSGi framework that can suit Spring. It led me to Spring Dynamic Module (SDM) and Gemini Blueprint (GB). SDM is dead and GB is not popular - I even can't find any tutorials (work with Spring). I'm thinking of an alternative way but I don't have much experience in this area. Does anyone have any suggestions for my project? We can leave OSGi, even Spring behind.
Any helps is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Comment: _I don't ask for a specific solution, or how can I write it. Even I don't need a system design_ I can do it by myself. What I'm confusing here is **a suggestion**? Like I can try Spring alter for Quarkus, etc. Does it make sense?

Comment: Suggestion are considered inviting opinions. I guess you might want to ask something along the line : in 2021, what standard solution that exist in Java to make a pluggable application like Jira/Confluence. You might want to describe a bit more what kind of application and plugin you're thinking of to have more accurate answers and be a bit less broad. If you do, edit your post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following approach for a maven+JavaEE project (with Thorntail, now called Quarkus), but I'm sure it is possible to do so for Spring as well.

You split your modules in two different maven projects: interfaces and implementations.

Let's say you want to have a module "Authentication" with OAUTH2 as implementation. You'll have a `authentication-interface` and a `authentication-oauth2` project. In the interfaces you have actually only `interface` classes and definition of classes used as parameters/return values for your interfaces.

You have then a main maven project, where actually the initialisation of your Spring application takes places. It will act as an "Orchestrator".
This project will have as hard dependency only the "authentication-interface" artifact and will use the [**ServiceLoader**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) approach to load an actual implementation of your interface(s). For this to work, the "authentication-oauth2" JAR must be available in the classpath/modulepath of your application at runtime.